# SharePoint OnLine Using Cmdlet New-SPWOPIBinding

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, pnp-powershell, cmdlets

I am a young SharePoint OnLine user.
I want Excel documents from all my sites to open directly with Excel and not Excel-OnLine.
As I have a lot of sites and it would be long to make the sites one by one, I try to use PowerShell without success :

```
Import-Module -Name OfficeWebApps 

$tenantName = "mytenant"
$username = "myAdminEmail@myEntreprise.eu"
$password = "myPassword"

$pnpModule = Get-Module SharePointPnPPowerShell* -ListAvailable
$pnpPath = $pnpModule.ModuleBase
Add-Type -Path "C:\PSTools\Modules\SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline\2.15.1705.0\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll" 
Add-Type -Path "C:\PSTools\Modules\SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline\2.15.1705.0\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll" 
Add-Type -Path "C:\PSTools\Modules\SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline\2.15.1705.0\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UserProfiles.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\PSTools\Modules\SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline\2.15.1705.0\Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.Client.Tenant.dll"

# internal params
$adminUrl = "https://$tenantName-admin.sharepoint.com"
$rootUrl = "https://$tenantName.sharepoint.com"
Write-Host *********************************
Write-Host "Admin Url : $adminUrl"
Write-Host "Root Url : $rootUrl"
Write-Host *********************************
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force 

# Admin connection
$adminCtx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($adminUrl) 

# Credential SharePoint Online for admin tenant
$credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($username, $securePassword) 
$adminCtx.Credentials = $credentials

New-SPWOPIBinding -ServerName "$tenantName.sharepoint.com" -Application "Excel"
```

I'm sure the path to PnP is good. Yet I get an error:

```
 "New-SPWOPIBinding : The term 'New-SPWOPIBinding' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the 
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:37 char:1
+ New-SPWOPIBinding -ServerName "$tenantName.sharepoint.com" -Applicati ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (New-SPWOPIBinding:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the documentation of the New-SPWOPIBinding, you see it is not meant for SharePoint online: 
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/new-spwopibinding?view=sharepoint-ps

I'm pretty sure you can't change this behavior with SharePoint online.

Update:

---

I stand corrected, I thought this was not possible with the new UI. 
The NEW-SPWOPIBinding definitely doesn't work. This is part of SharePoint onpremises. However, you are correct in the post below, that you can enable a feature that changes the default behavior.

I tested this script and can confirm that it works, although the users will likely get a mixed experience:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename
Enable-PnPFeature -Identity 8a4b8de2-6fd8-41e9-923c-c7c3c00f8295 -Force -Scope Site
```

In the second command it's important to specify the -Scope Site as this is a site collection feature en the cmdlet defaults to the web scope.

Comment: Yet in this article, he says it's usable for SharePoint Online No?

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-set-the-default-open-behaviour-or-configure-office-files-open-by-default/

Comment: I did reference the official Microsoft documentation. For SharePoint online you can only use the SharePoint online management shell. And here's a list of the cmdlets: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/?view=sharepoint-ps

Comment: And your exact error states that the cmdlet is not available, as would seem logical based on the official docs.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your answer! 
So I'm condemned to settle each site one by one?

Comment: I think so. I haven't tried myself but my expectation would be that this can't be changed. Especially in the modern ui.

Comment: I have the list of my SharePoint sites. I will try to find a Cmdlet that allows to change the option in each site one after the other.
Normally in SharePoit, everything that is doable with the mouse is doable with a  script!

Comment: There's probably a command with Pnp. 
For example to change the logo of a site, there are 
Set-PnPWeb -SiteLogoUrl $PictureUrl -Web $web

Comment: It can be done with PowerShell PnP! 
You have to activate the function with "Enable-PnPFeature", however this does not work for me. I must have made a mistake in my PowerShell code?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution :

```
######################################################################################
## Script permettant d'activer une fonctionnalité sur une liste de sites
## La fonctionalitée est définie par un ID
## Il est nécéssaire d'avoir installé PowerShell PnP et lancé PowerShell en mode admin
## ==> Install-Module SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline -AllowClobber
######################################################################################

$username = Read-Host "Login (Adresse e-mail Admin) : "
$password = Read-Host -Prompt "Mot de passe de l'utilisateur $username" –AsSecureString
$Credential = New-Object PSCredential($userName,$passWord)
$outputfile = "C:\PSTools\sites_all.csv"

######################################################################################
## Main
######################################################################################
$csv = import-csv $outputfile -delimiter ";"
$indexMax = $csv.Count
$index = 0
$csv | ForEach-Object {
    try {

        $index ++
        $URL = $_.Url
        #Permet de sauter les URL incorrectes
        if ($URL.StartsWith("*")) { return } 

        write-host "************************************************" -foregroundcolor Gray
        write-host "$index / $indexMax  Activation de la fonctionnalité sur le site $($_.Title)" -foregroundcolor Gray
        write-host "************************************************" -foregroundcolor Gray

        #Connexion au site
        Connect-PnPOnline -Url $URL -Credentials $Credential

        #Activation de la fonctionnalitée
        Enable-PnPFeature -Identity 8a4b8de2-6fd8-41e9-923c-c7c3c00f8295 -Force -Scope Site
        Disconnect-PnPOnline 
        write-host "Fonctionnalité Activée !" -foregroundcolor Green
        }
    catch{
        write-host "/!\ Fonctionnalité NON Activée ! - ERREUR INCONNUE /!\" -foregroundcolor Red
    }
}
write-host "Fin du script" -foregroundcolor Blue
```